# How to listen for Advisories on Slave-Brokers

Tags: replication, monitoring, activemq-classic

I'm using consumers for Advisory-Topics to monitor activemq brokers. Now i have to add direct replication to my architecture.

Is it possible to create a consumer for Advisories on this slave?

it seem that even vm://... connections are refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a broker is run in pure master / slave then the Slave will not start its transport connectors so you cannot listen to advisories from a slave.

Comment: not totaly correct: vm:// connection from within the same jvm will work.